# c slower than java when summing a billion integers

Tags: java, c++

This is the case:

```
cat sum100000000.cpp && cat sum100000000.java 
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  long N=1000000000,sum=0;
  for( long i=0; i<N; i++ ) sum+= i;
  printf("%ld\n",sum);
}


public class sum100000000 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sum=0;
        for(long i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) sum += i;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
time ./a.out && time java sum100000000
499999999500000000

real    0m2.675s
user    0m2.673s
sys 0m0.002s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
499999999500000000

real    0m0.439s
user    0m0.470s
sys 0m0.027s
```

Not seeing anything unusual in the disassembled binary. but seems c binary is significantly slower. which  I couldn't understand.

My guess is that there might be some problem with the toolchain

```
clang -v
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

uname -a
Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Add: c / cpp compiled without any special binary. This is not changing the result anyways.

```
gcc sum1b.cpp
clang sum1b.cpp
```

Add: for those concerned with llvm, really not changing anything

```
$ gcc sum100000000.cpp && time ./a.out
gcc sum100000000.cpp && time ./a.out
499999999500000000

real    0m2.722s
user    0m2.717s
sys 0m0.003s
```

Modification: O2 is a lot faster: but that looks like a cheat

```
$ otool -tV a.out
otool -tV a.out
a.out:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100000f50    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f51    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f54    leaq    0x37(%rip), %rdi ## literal pool for: "%ld
"
0000000100000f5b    movabsq $0x6f05b59b5e49b00, %rsi
0000000100000f65    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100000f67    callq   0x100000f70 ## symbol stub for: _printf
0000000100000f6c    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100000f6e    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f6f    ret
```

I am convinced now that this is related with Optimisation, so now the question more on what did the JIT do exactly to speed up this calculation?

Comment: Don't you mean `long long` instead of `long` in C?

Comment: That's not C, that's C++. How are you compiling (what compiler flags)?

Comment: (Hint: try `-O2`. Will be faster than Java.)

Comment: @Mat, what optimisation can be applied on this

Comment: @zinking: bloody magic. The assembly doesn't even contain a loop, the sum is computed by the compiler.

Comment: @Mat: Not necessarily, remember the JVM does JIT in hotspots (and the above definitely is a hotspot). In fact, for me `gcc -O2 sum.c` results in a binary that performs almost identically (ever so slightly slower) than the equivalent Java: http://pastie.org/9704483

Comment: ohh! i think that's why people say java is f**#ing fast

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is simplest form that can even be written in assembly, what kind of optimisation JIT is applying? cheated?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: sure the JVM can JIT that as much as it wants. Unlikely though that for such a thing the JVM startup overhead will beat the optimized C++ version. Both clang and GCC optimize the loop out here (GCC 4.7, clang 3.5). This "benchmark" is just yet another benchmark that doesn't prove anything.

Comment: There is a factor here: you use LLVM. I don't know how it works exactly, but I take it this is not really "real" machine code, is it?

Comment: @fge: don't be fooled by the "VM" in LLVM, the clang C and C++ compilers generate native code.

Comment: @Mat: Remember there's startup for a C binary as well. I would expect the C binary to win (by a tiny bit), though, and was surprised it didn't with just `-O2`.

Comment: @Mat hmm OK, I thought there were an intermediary representation generated or something

Comment: Why are you using non-const `N` in C, but a constant value in Java, for `1000000000` ?

Comment: Isn't there a bunch of integer overflow with this? Are they treated the same by both the JVM and native asm?

Comment: @Eric: Good thought, but no, these are 64-bit two's complement integers (always in the Java case, and in the C case as well on my machine anyway); max positive value is 9223372036854775807. `sum` never gets anywhere near overflowing.

Comment: @Ajay: Good catch. Didn't end up making much of a difference, but still...

Comment: Why is O2 a cheat when you are comparing performance? Of course C is slower when you artificially cripple it.

Comment: Your C version has undefined behavior due to overflows if long is 32 bit. This makes the benchmark invalid. Slow performance is an acceptable effect of UB.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not it would make a difference, but you should use `System.out.format("%ld\n",sum)` in your Java code if you want to have it as close as possible to your C++ code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The issue is most likely that you're not compiling the C version with optimization enabled. If you enable aggressive optimization, the binary produced by `gcc` should win. The JVM's JIT is good, but the simple fact is that the JVM has to load and then apply JIT at runtime; `gcc` can optimize the binary at compile-time.

Leaving off all `gcc` flags gives me a binary that performs fairly slowly, like yours. Using `-O2` gives me a binary that *just barely* loses out to the Java version. Using `-O3` gives me one that easily beats the Java version. (This is on my Linux Mint 16 64-bit machine with `gcc` 4.8.1 and Java 1.8.0_20 [e.g., Java 8 Update 20].) [larsmans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166749/larsmans) examined the disassembly of the `-O3` version and assures me that the compiler isn't precomputing the result (my C and assembly fu is *very* weak these days; many thanks to larsmans for double-checking that). Interestingly, though, thanks to investigation by [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat), it looks like that's actually a byproduct of my using `gcc` 4.8.1; earlier and later versions of `gcc` seem to be willing to precompute the result. Happy accident for us, though.

Here's my pure C version [I've also updated it to account for [Ajay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815471/c-slower-than-java-when-summing-a-billion-integers/26815565#comment42202197_26815471) about your using a constant in the Java version, but the variable `N` in the C version (didn't make any real difference, but...)]:

`sum.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  long sum=0;
  long i;
  for( i=0; i<1000000000; i++ ) sum+= i;
  printf("%ld\n",sum);
}
```

My Java version is unchanged from yours other than that I lost track of the zeroes too easily:

`sum.java`:

```
public class sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sum=0;
        for(long i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) sum += i;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Results:

C binary run (compiled via `gcc sum.c`):

```
$ time ./a.out
499999999500000000

real    0m2.436s
user    0m2.429s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Java run (compiled with no special flags, run with no special runtime flags):

```
$ time java sum
499999999500000000

real    0m0.691s
user    0m0.684s
sys 0m0.020s
```

Java run (compiled with no special flags, run with `-server -noverify`, *tiny* improvement):

```
$ time java -server -noverify sum
499999999500000000

real    0m0.651s
user    0m0.649s
sys 0m0.016s
```

C binary run (compiled via `gcc -O2 sum.c`):

```
$ time ./a.out
499999999500000000

real    0m0.733s
user    0m0.732s
sys 0m0.000s
```

C binary run (compiled via `gcc -O3 sum.c`):

```
$ time ./a.out
499999999500000000

real    0m0.373s
user    0m0.372s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Here's the `main` result of `objdump -d a.out` on my `-O3` version:

```
0000000000400470 :
  400470:   66 0f 6f 1d 08 02 00    movdqa 0x208(%rip),%xmm3        # 400680 
  400477:   00 
  400478:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40047a:   66 0f ef c9             pxor   %xmm1,%xmm1
  40047e:   66 0f 6f 05 ea 01 00    movdqa 0x1ea(%rip),%xmm0        # 400670 
  400485:   00 
  400486:   eb 0c                   jmp    400494 
  400488:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40048f:   00 
  400490:   66 0f 6f c2             movdqa %xmm2,%xmm0
  400494:   66 0f 6f d0             movdqa %xmm0,%xmm2
  400498:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  40049b:   66 0f d4 c8             paddq  %xmm0,%xmm1
  40049f:   3d 00 65 cd 1d          cmp    $0x1dcd6500,%eax
  4004a4:   66 0f d4 d3             paddq  %xmm3,%xmm2
  4004a8:   75 e6                   jne    400490 
  4004aa:   66 0f 6f e1             movdqa %xmm1,%xmm4
  4004ae:   be 64 06 40 00          mov    $0x400664,%esi
  4004b3:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  4004b8:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4004ba:   66 0f 73 dc 08          psrldq $0x8,%xmm4
  4004bf:   66 0f d4 cc             paddq  %xmm4,%xmm1
  4004c3:   66 0f 7f 4c 24 e8       movdqa %xmm1,-0x18(%rsp)
  4004c9:   48 8b 54 24 e8          mov    -0x18(%rsp),%rdx
  4004ce:   e9 8d ff ff ff          jmpq   400460
```

As I say, my assembly-fu is very weak, but I'm seeing a loop there, rather than the compiler having done the math.

And just for completeness, the `main` part of the result of `javap -c sum`:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: lconst_0
       1: lstore_1
       2: lconst_0
       3: lstore_3
       4: lload_3
       5: ldc2_w        #2                  // long 1000000000l
       8: lcmp
       9: ifge          23
      12: lload_1
      13: lload_3
      14: ladd
      15: lstore_1
      16: lload_3
      17: lconst_1
      18: ladd
      19: lstore_3
      20: goto          4
      23: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      26: lload_1
      27: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(J)V
      30: return
```

It's not precomputing the result at the bytecode level; I can't say what the JIT is doing.

Comment: On my box, the C++ version is a bit faster with `gcc -O2`, and a lot faster at `-O3`. Inspection of the assembler shows the compiler is not doing the math.

Comment: @larsmans: Yeah, with `-O3` on my machine, I get real of 0.366s. Thanks for checking the disassembly, I'll update the above to add that.

Comment: http://goo.gl/Fn9U80 - no assembly wizard either, but it's pretty clear what this example does: load a constant in a register, load the address of `"%ld\n" in another and call printf.

Comment: I'm convinced that this is related with optimisation, but how could Java JIT that to be faster, like starts to do the ADD and then suddenly uses the cheating method ?

Comment: @Mat: Very interesting. `objdump` shows something completely different for me than that website does.

Comment: @Mat Looks like GCC 4.9.0 got a better optimizer. I'm using 4.8.1, which does some loop transformation, but not this.

Comment: Seems like an optimization "bug" in 4.8. Both 4.7.2 and 4.9.3 precompute the loop at `-O2`, 4.8.2 doesn't even at `-O3`... interesting ;-) (Tip: use `-save-temps` and you'll have a `.s` file with the generated assembly, slightly easier than objdump)

Comment: @Mat: Yeah, I was playing with that website, and GCC **4.4** was more than happy to precompute the result, but 4.8 wasn't!

Comment: @zinking: I doubt the JIT is cheating. It's just that it gets aggressive with register reuse and such. The unoptimized C binary doesn't. The optimized one does, and so ends up easily beating the Java version by not having the JVM startup and JIT to do.

Comment: @Mat Or just `gcc -S` :)

Comment: Note that the comparison is with 500000000 (0x1dcd6500), so GCC 4.8 does understand that it can halve the number of iterations.

Comment: Notably, -O3 has vectorised the loop with SSE to do two partial sums in parallel, which is probably why it's twice as fast.

Comment: Actually this is the first time I've seen that `-O3` is faster than `-O2`. I always find their speed difference negligible.

Comment: It is impossible for a JIT to cheat on a method that runs a single time. While in principle the JIT can and does replace computations by their invariant result, that result must be computed at runtime which takes at least the time… well that is required for the computation. So for a JIT, this type of optimization (“cheating”) helps only for methods executed more than once.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense to optimize `java` byte code when comparing with `gcc` optimized byte code. Accepted answer did not include `-server -noverify` switches. Optionally, `-Xcomp` could be applied but it is not recommended.

1. CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
2. java version "1.8.0_25"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
3. gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

sum.java with flags:

```
time java -server -noverify sum
499999999500000000

real    0m0.299s
user    0m0.303s
sys 0m0.004s
```

and sum.c with 03 flag:

```
time ./a.out 
499999999500000000

real    0m0.233s
user    0m0.233s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: helpful to know these options, but still don't know why java is faster.

Comment: @zinking: It isn't, see above (.299 vs. .233).

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. I've updated the accepted answer to use those flags; difference was trivial.